# How to load images and cache in ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed LCD display like widget, I have 10 digits images and for every digit on display ( max 6 ) I have  and on click I change picture on div ( jquery attr('src','url'). My question is how to load all this 10 images in ready function ? I need to avoid flickering if connection is slow ( It flicker first time ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to create a "sprite".

A sprite is a single image that has all those digits stacked, and you'll then apply different `background-position`'s according to which digit you want.

You can use [spriteme.org](http://spriteme.org/) to help you with creating the sprites.

Here's one I've made some time ago for one of my projects:

[image: Digits Sprite]

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery preload](http://www.google.pl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20preload) will do. Of course a sprite (see @Joseph Silber's answer) is a "more professional" option, but will require a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

Place all of the images in som kind of hidden div

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <img src="a.png"/>
    <img src="b.png"/>
    <img src="c.png"/>
</div>
```

This should ensure loading the images.

Comment: just a quick question but shouldnt it be `visibility:hidden` since `display:none` isn't rendered at all in my understanding?

Comment: Actually a good question, which I'm not sure about. I've never actually tried :) Answer from @Joseph Silber is anywho much smarter.